# Images from sqlite3 database do not display in treeview tkinter

Tags: python, image, sqlite, tkinter, blob

I am creating a GUI which displays data in a treeview from a sqlite database. I have managed to dsiplay the text and integer data. However, images are still a problem. I have referred to so many questions on this site and other sources but nothing has worked yet.
The code below displays from a database without any data in the image column.

```
def View():
      conn = sqlite3.connect("waziiInv.db")
      cursor = conn.cursor()
      conn.text_factory = str
      cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM Items""")
      rows= cursor.fetchall()
      for row in rows:
            tree1.insert("",tk.END,values=row)
            cursor.close()
```

The outcome is below;
[result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0oAw.png)

I have tried with the database image column filled as blob data. [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR85R.png). Here is the code I use for this;

```
 def View():
      conn = sqlite3.connect("waziiInv.db")
      cursor = conn.cursor()
      conn.text_factory = str
      cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM Items""")
      rows= cursor.fetchall()
      print("Total rows are:  ", len(rows))
    
      for row in rows:
            img = Image.open(tk.io.BytesIO(row[1]))
            img.thumbnail((50,50))
            img=tk.ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
            img.show()
            tree1.insert("",tk.END,values=row)
      cursor.close()
```

When I click the load button, there is an error  "sqlite3.OperationalError: Could not decode to UTF-8 column 'Image' with text '\ufffdPNG". I undestand I have to convert the blob data to a different format. However, all the resources I got work with uploading data only instead of an existing column or works with one image.
My goal is to display the entire image column in the treeview alongside the rest of the columns with a click of the button.

This is my first python project so am still lacking. Apologies on the image links. Could not add them anyother way.

Someone please help with the solutions or tips. Thank you.

Comment: You can only show image in column `#0` using `image` option of `.insert()`.